# DevComponents - Dotnetbar2 add a style by runtime

Tags: winforms, styles, dotnetbar

I want to add a style to a Combobox at runtime like this:

```
Dim cbo as DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ComboBoxEx
cbo = new DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.ComboBoxEx

With cbo

    .Style=eDotNetBarStyle.Windows7
    .width=200px

End With

ctl.Add(cbo)
```

But it does not work. The Style is the normal Windows-Controls Style. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of the DevComponent(DotNetBar) my current is 11.03 and You just need to add a StyleManager to your proyect, and all the controls on the form youchose to have this style will have it without writting any code. One of the properties from the StyleManager is the Theme (Office2007, Office2010, VS2012, Windows 7, Metro, etc) you just set it and all the controls from the DevComponents will change to fit this setting.